# Plot a complex function in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, visualization, plot, complex-numbers

How can I make a Mathematica graphics that copies the behaviour of [complex_plot](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/plot/complex_plot.html) in sage? i.e.

> ... takes a complex function of one
> variable,  and plots output of the
> function over the specified xrange and
> yrange as demonstrated below. The
> magnitude of the output is indicated
> by the brightness (with zero being
> black and infinity being white) while
> the argument is represented by the hue
> (with red being positive real, and
> increasing through orange, yellow, ...
> as the argument increases).

Here's an example (stolen from M. Hampton of [Neutral Drifts](http://neutraldrifts.blogspot.com/)) of the zeta function with overlayed contours of absolute value:

[image: zeta function complex_plot]

In the Mathematica documentation page [Functions Of Complex Variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FunctionsOfComplexVariables.html) it says that you can visualize complex functions using `ContourPlot` and `DensityPlot` "potentially coloring by phase". But the problem is in both types of plots, `ColorFunction` only takes a single variable equal to the contour or density at the point - so it seems impossible to make it colour the phase/argument while plotting the absolute value. Note that this is not a problem with `Plot3D` where all 3 parameters `(x,y,z)` get passed to `ColorFunction`.

I know that there are other ways to visualize complex functions - such as the "neat example" in the [Plot3D docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot3D.html#347161167), but that's not what I want.

Also, I do have [one solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385103/plot-a-complex-function-in-mathematica/5386801#5386801) (that has actually been used to generate some graphics used in Wikipedia), but it defines a fairly low level function, and I think that it should be possible with a high level function like `ContourPlot` or `DensityPlot`. Not that this should stop you from giving your favourite approach that uses a lower level construction!

---

**Edit:**  There were some nice articles by Michael Trott in the Mathematica journal on:
Visualizing Riemann surfaces [of algebraic functions](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/3014/), [IIa](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/901/), [IIb](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/1987/), [IIc](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/3900/), [IId](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/4556/).
Visualizing Riemann surfaces [demo](http://library.wolfram.com/examples/riemannsurface/).
[The Return of Riemann surfaces (updates for Mma v6)](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v10i4/Corner10-4.html)

Of course, Michael Trott wrote the [Mathematica guide books](http://www.mathematicaguidebooks.org/), which contain many beautiful graphics, but seem to have fallen behind the accelerated Mathematica release schedule!

Comment: I haven't read the question yet, but +1 for the lovely plot :)

Comment: @belisarius: It's not my plot, but thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you can't pass (x, y, z) into ColorFunction in DensityPlot? I've been able to do something along the lines of DensityPlot[..., ColorFunction->Function[{x, y, z}, f[x,y,z]]]

Comment: @MikeBantegui: Note that only the `x` parameter in your function can be used and corresponds to the density at each point.  See the first entry in the "MORE INFORMATION" section of the [ColorFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html) docs. It's strange that it doesn't yield a warning...

Comment: @Mike, only `x` is given any info, if you use `ColorFunction->Function[{x,y,z}, Hue@(y/maxy)]` you only get gray. But, using `x/maxx` gives you something.

Comment: @rcollyer @belisarius @Brett: Do you think that it's just coincidence that Stephen Wolfram put [Phase of a Complex Polynomial](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PhaseOfAComplexPolynomial/) on the demonstration site a week after this SO question?

Comment: should probably be migrated to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's my attempt.  I winged the color function a bit.

```
ParametricPlot[
 (*just need a vis function that will allow x and y to be in the color function*)
 {x, y}, {x, -6, 3}, {y, -3, 3},

 (*color and mesh functions don't trigger refinement, so just use a big grid*)
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> 50,

 (*turn off scaling so we can do computations with the actual complex values*)
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,

 ColorFunction -> (Hue[
     (*hue according to argument, with shift so arg(z)==0 is red*)
     Rescale[Arg[Zeta[# + I #2]], {-Pi, Pi}, {0, 1} + 0.5], 1,

     (*fudge brightness a bit: 
       0.1 keeps things from getting too dark, 
       2 forces some actual bright areas*)
     Rescale[Log[Abs[Zeta[# + I #2]]], {-Infinity, Infinity}, {0.1, 2}]] &),

 (*mesh lines according to magnitude, scaled to avoid the pole at z=1*)
 MeshFunctions -> {Log[Abs[Zeta[#1 + I #2]]] &},

 (*turn off axes, because I don't like them with frames*)
 Axes -> False
 ]
```

[image: complex plot]

I haven't thought of a good way to get the mesh lines to vary in color.  Easiest is probably to just generate them with `ContourPlot` instead of `MeshFunctions`.

Comment: Nice! It's very close to the solution that I'd seen which uses `RegionPlot[True, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, opts...]` as the base `Graphics` object.

Comment: @BrettChampion Nice plot! Is there an easy way to include some kind of plotlegend where hue runs from -pi to pi ?

Answer (score 15):

Here's my variation on the function given by [Axel Boldt](http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/~axel/graphs/) who was inspired by [Jan Homann](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Jan_Homann/Mathematics). Both of the linked to pages have some nice graphics.

```
ComplexGraph[f_, {xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := 
 RegionPlot[True, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, opts, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, With[{ff = f[x + I y]}, 
    Hue[(2. Pi)^-1 Mod[Arg[ff], 2 Pi], 1, 1 - (1.2 + 10 Log[Abs[ff] + 1])^-1]]]
 ]
```

Then we can make the plot without the contours by running

```
ComplexGraph[Zeta, {-7, 3}, {-3, 3}]
```

[image: Zeta without contours]

We can add contours by either copying [Brett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385103/plot-a-complex-function-in-mathematica/5386169#5386169) by using and showing a specific plot mesh in the ComplexGraph:

```
ComplexGraph[Zeta, {-7, 3}, {-3, 3}, Mesh -> 30, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Log[Abs[Zeta[#1 + I #2]]] &},
 MeshStyle -> {{Thin, Black}, None}, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

or by combining with a contour plot like

```
ContourPlot[Abs[Zeta[x + I y]], {x, -7, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100,
 Contours -> Exp@Range[-7, 1, .25], ContourShading -> None];
Show[{ComplexGraph[Zeta, {-7, 3}, {-3, 3}],%}]
```

[image: with contours]

Answer (score 8):

Not a proper answer, for two reasons:

- This is not what you asked for
- I'm shamelessly using Brett's code

Anyway, for me the following is much more clear to interpret (brightness is ... well, just brightness):

[image]

Brett's code almost intact:

```
Plot3D[
 Log[Abs[Zeta[x + I y]]], {x, -6, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 (*color and mesh functions don't trigger refinement,so just use a big grid*)
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 Mesh -> 50, 
 (*turn off scaling so we can do computations with the actual complex values*)
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[
     (*hue according to argument,with shift so arg(z)==0 is red*)
     Rescale[Arg[Zeta[# + I #2]], {-Pi, Pi}, {0, 1} + 0.5], 
     1,(*fudge brightness a bit:
     0.1 keeps things from getting too dark,
     2 forces some actual bright areas*)
     Rescale[Log[Abs[Zeta[# + I #2]]], {-Infinity, Infinity}, {0.1, 2}]] &),
     (*mesh lines according to magnitude,scaled to avoid the pole at z=1*)
     MeshFunctions -> {Log[Abs[Zeta[#1 + I #2]]] &},
     (*turn off axes,because I don't like them with frames*)
     Axes -> False]
```

Comment: Not a proper answer, but I agree - it does make some aspects more clear and it is pretty! +1

Answer (score 0):

For everyone interested in achieving this in *Python*, I created [cplot](https://github.com/nschloe/cplot). Install with

```
pip install cplot
```

This plots the [domain-coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) plot of the [Taylor polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of degree 6 of exp:

```py
import cplot


def exp_taylor(z):
    s = 1.0
    t = 1.0
    for k in range(1, 7):
        t *= z / k
        s += t
    return s

plt = cplot.plot(
    exp_taylor,
    # or something simpler
    # lambda z: z ** 6 + 1,
    (-5, +5, 400),
    (-5, +5, 400),
)
plt.show()
```

[image]